# How to delete all files with filenames containing spaces on Linux?

Tags: linux, csh

cannot delete my own question, overwrite instead

Comment: I managed to delete everything myself using vi to edit the temporary file, after discovering that there were also filenames which contained parenthesis -- which the shell also does not like....

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let's do this progressively.

And let's presume that you really *do* want to look in subdirectories as well, even though that's only implied in your question.

As a first pass, this is just a simple exercise in passing a wildcard to the `find` command, remembering to quote it of course, and executing the `rm` command for every file found:

```
find $BASE_DIR/ -name '* *' -exec rm {} \;
```

But of course that's dreadfully inefficient.  It starts up a whole `rm` process for each individual file.  So while we could take a short detour through `\+` that's not where we are going to end up, so let's take the shorter route and bring in `xargs` to batch up the filenames into groups:

```
find $BASE_DIR/ -name '* *' -print | xargs rm
```

But that has two security holes.  First, if any filename found happens to begin with a minus sign `rm` will treat it as a command-line option rather than a filename, and generate an error.  (The `-exec rm {}` version also has this problem.)  Second, filenames containing whitespace will not be handled properly by `xargs`, as you've noticed.  So a further iteration is to make this a little more bulletproof:

```
find $BASE_DIR/ -name '* *' -print0 | xargs -0 rm --
```

And, of course, there are the interactive features of `rm` that you probably don't want:

```
find $BASE_DIR/ -name '* *' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f --
```

The `-print0` and `-0` options are not standard, but the GNU `find` and `xargs`, as well as the FreeBSD `find` and `xargs`, understand them.  However, even this is improvable.  We don't need to spawn any extra processes at all.  The GNU and FreeBSD `find`s can both invoke the `unlink(2)` system call directly:

```
find $BASE_DIR/ -name '* *' -delete
```

As a last preventative measure to stop you doing more than you intended in certain circumstances, remember that the filesystem can contain more than just regular files:

```
find $BASE_DIR/ -name '* *' -type f -delete
```

Comment: … so basically, what I wrote ;) Nice explanation, although I'd recommend putting the most secure variant at the *top* of the post, not at the bottom.

Comment: No: what **I** wrote, back on 2014-01-09, tracking the _1 character difference in the question_ and the slight changes necessary for the C shell.

Comment: True, I just saw that I answered that as well. Which kind of makes it a duplicate, especially since the answer is exactly the same, just swapping one character.

Comment: I did wonder why you'd not marked it as a duplicate.  I held off doing so thinking that you must have had your reasons.  I nearly put "Duplicate question therefore duplicate answer." at the top, though.  (-:

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
rm *\ *
```

or

```
rm *' '*
```

or

```
rm *" "*
```

You might try 'ls' before doing 'rm' so you are sure what you are doing.

Comment: It's not recursive, perhaps that's why the OP didn't use `rm`. (Not that it cannot be done, but…)